# sql create function converting string to ascii integer

Tags: mysql, sorting, stored-procedures

I want to sort records by its question no, e.g.: 1 , 2c  , 10 , 12a. Is it good to convert them into sum of ascii code? if yes, what would be the error in the following code creating sql funcion? if no, what would be the better way to do that.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.asciiCodeInteger (@string AS VARCHAR(3))
    RETURNS int
    AS
    BEGIN
      DECLARE @result int;
      DECLARE @char CHAR(1);

      SET @result = 0;

      WHILE LEN(@string) > 0
      BEGIN
        SET @char = LEFT(@string, 1);
        SET @result = @result + ASCII(@char);
        SET @string = SUBSTRING(@string, 2, LEN(@string));
      END
      RETURN (@result);
    END
```

Comment: Please add the database type. MS SQL? MySQL? Sybase?

Comment: Re-tagged with `mysql` based on the comments to the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to change some logic like,

1. Declare @position=1
2. @Char =SUBSTRING(@string, @position, 1)
3. Modify only @position not @string.

Solution look like, (Unable to run on SQL Fiddle)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.asciiCodeInteger (@string AS VARCHAR(3))
    RETURNS int
    AS
    BEGIN
      DECLARE @result int;
      DECLARE @char CHAR(1);
      DECLARE @position int;
      SET @position = 1;
      SET @result = 0;

      WHILE @position <= LEN(@string)
      BEGIN
        SET @char = SUBSTRING(@string, @position, 1);
        SET @result = @result + ASCII(@char);
        SET @position = @position + 1
      END
      RETURN (@result);
    END
```

Comment: oh thanks, but for some reasons, syntax error occurs #1064. is it caused by the mysql server version?

Comment: I am trying on MS SQL server, please check edited solution for MY SQL, only change in Len(@string)